# Severe lag getting a json object from the web in C# form

Tags: c#, json, http

I am just kind of playing around in visual studio, and made a small application.

I can do this same thing in Java in about 20 minutes, but since I have no experience with C# its a bit harder since I dont know many of its methods.

That said, I built a simple form with 3 controls- a button, a label, and a textfield.

The buttons onClick method performs the getPrice method, given below. Roughly commented, it connects to a website, and grabs a json object.

Because I don't know how to use json in C#, I handled it by cutting out a substring which should be the current bitcoin price for that market whose API I pull the data from.

My problem is that, when you click the get price button, the application pauses and is unresponsive, and then eventually sets the new price data to the textBox1 field.

Is there something in my code causing the lag, or is it just because I am using a web request? I mean,  I was able to perform this exact same action (but using the json element instead of a substring ) in Java with no lag, so I guess I dont get it.

```
private void getPrice()
    {
        string[] result;
        var json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker");
        int startIndex = json.IndexOf("last\":");
        int endIndex = json.IndexOf(",\"buy\"", startIndex);
        string amountString = json.Substring(startIndex + 6, endIndex - startIndex - 7);
        textBox1.Text = amountString;
    }
```

Comment: Use `await WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(....)` and mark your `getPrice` method `async`.  This moves the operation off the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient is blocking the UI thread. Operations like this should be done in a background thread. If you're using C# 5, then research the async/await pattern and use it with the HttpClient class.

[Example code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient)